# Windbg ethread - IrpList location

Tags: windows, debugging, memory, windbg

I'm currently struggling to make sense of the output from Windbg.

What I'm trying to do is find out how many IRPs (Interrupt Request Packets) are queued in a particular thread, so here is what I currently have:

```
lkd> !thread
THREAD fffffa8001fce270
IRP List:
fffffa8001cf3b60
...
```

So this tells me that the current thread has one IRP in it's list, and it's address.

However, the next command is what's confusing me slightly:

```
lkd> ??@$thread->IrpList
struct _LIST_ENTRY
[ 0xfffffa8001cf3b80 - 0xfffffa8001cf3b80 ]
+0x000 Flink   0xfffffa8001cf3b80 _LIST_ENTRY [ 0xfffffa8001fce658 -     0xfffffa8001fce658]
+0x000 Blink   0xfffffa8001cf3b80 _LIST_ENTRY [ 0xfffffa8001fce658 -     0xfffffa8001fce658]
```

All of this information is coming out of the _ETHREAD structure, and according to windbg the offset for the 'IrpList' element in the structure is 0x3e8.

So if the thread (_ETHREAD) starts at offset 0xfffffa8001fce270, the IrpList element should be at offset 0xfffffa8001fce658 (0xfffffa8001fce270 + 0x3e8)

However, I don't fully understand why windbg is reporting the IRP List entry at offset 0xfffffa8001cf3b80.

I'm probably getting the wrong end of the stick here, but if anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list address is not 0xfffffa8001cf3b80.  That's the address of the list entry in the IRP, which is at IRP+0x20 (0xfffffa8001cf3b60 + 0x20 = 0xfffffa8001cf3b80).  The list entry address in the ETHREAD is 0xfffffa8001fce658 (0xfffffa8001fce658 - fffffa8001fce270 = 0x3e8).

Comment: Thanks the info Steve.  I'm still a little confused though.  When I look in the list_entry for the IrpList, all I see are the same values for the flink, and blink.  I'm not sure where windbg is getting the 0xfffffa8001cf3b80 value from.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The values are the same because there is only one IRP in the list.  The 3b80 value is the address of the list entry in the IRP structure located at 3b60.

Comment: One more thing...the 3b80 value is found in the IRP list entry of the ETHREAD structure.  That's where the debugger is getting it from.

Comment: Thanks again Steve, however I think I'm doing something wrong in that case.  As another example, I can see an ethread structure at fffffa8001f8d310, with the IrpList _list_entry at fffffa8001f8d6f8, however both the flink and blink in that list just contain fffffa8001f8d6f8.  Is there something wrong with the image?

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong.  When the values of FLink and Blink both point to the address of the list entry itself, it means that the list is empty.

Comment: That's what I thought, however windbg is saying that there is a IRP at that address.  Hence my confusion!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34556/discussion-between-tony-and-steve-johnson)